# CSS can't select one element but selects other elements

Tags: html, css

For some reason my CSS file can not select the ul element. It selects p elements easily though. When i paste css code in html file it works. BUT when styling is in css file, only "p" works

```css
<style>
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
p {
  font-size:100px;
}
</style>
```

```html
<!<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head> 
  <link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
  <title> abc</title>
</head>
<body>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="http://kzcanada.club/"> На Главную</a> </li>
    <li><a href="#">Контакты</a></li>
  </ul>
<p>sdsdasd</p>
```

Comment: remove `<style></style>` when writing inside a CSS file. They are only need if you will put the CSS inside the HTML

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is simply because you put the `<style>` tag *inside* the CSS section of a StackSnippet. As `<style>` is an HTML element, you can only use it inside of the HTML section; the CSS section is reserved for the styles themselves.

Removing this `<style>` tag from the CSS section shows your code working as expected:

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

p {
  font-size: 100px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="http://kzcanada.club/"> На Главную</a> </li>
    <li><a href="#">Контакты</a></li>
  </ul>
  <p>sdsdasd</p>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is because you are trying to use `<style></style>` tag inside a CSS file, which is absolutely wrong. See this:

```css
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

p {
    font-size: 100px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <title> abc</title>
</head>

<body>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="http://kzcanada.club/"> На Главную</a> </li>
        <li><a href="#">Контакты</a></li>
    </ul>
    <p>sdsdasd</p>
</body>
```